# How to use common log4j.xml settings for across the Application WAR files in GlassFish?

Tags: java, log4j, glassfish

I want to use single(or externalize) log4j.xml to control logging settings from outside of all the application war files. Do I need to use JVM Options like -Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/log4j.xml? Where to put log4j.xml so that it will be accessible by all the applications that are deployed